# Empty Entitlements files after adding App Groups capabilities

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I created an app group identifier on our company account and link to a couple of apps id in order to use it on a watch kit app we are developing.

The bundle id of the apps looks like this:

```
App:   com.company.app
Watch: com.company.app.watchapp 
Group: group.com.company.app
```

After that, go to Xcode targets / capabilities and when enable app groups it creates an empty entitlements file. When I click to select the app groups, it creates a new empty entitlements file. See the images below.

[image]
[image]

Additionally the first point remain with error. So, I hit the fix issue button. A new empty entitlements file appears.

[image]
[image]

Of course, whatever action involving groups like `containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier` or `initWithSuiteName` does not work.

This is how all created entitlements files looks like:

[image]

Any clues on how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix it, I changed an accented letter from the target.

The project language is Spanish, and the original target name's was like `León`. After changing it to `Leon`, the problem was solved, and entitlements was generated as it should be.

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you changed in your project to get it to work? We seem to be running into the same problem, but trying to rename the target itself leads to XCode crashing and messing up the project.